# Create an instance of org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy using SPEL

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm having a difficulty understanding how to configure the following.

Since spring-kafka:2.8.4 thee `KafkaListener` interface can be configured with a filter which will be applied to all incoming messages, the Javadoc for the `filter` method:

```
    /**
     * Set an {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy} bean
     * name to override the strategy configured on the container factory. If a SpEL
     * expression is provided ({@code #{...}}), the expression can either evaluate to a
     * {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy} instance or
     * a bean name.
     * @return the error handler.
     * @since 2.8.4
     */
    String filter() default "";
```

RecordFilterStrategy has a single method:

```
    /**
     * Return true if the record should be discarded.
     * @param consumerRecord the record.
     * @return true to discard.
     */
    boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<K, V> consumerRecord);
```

Basically I need to create a kind of a lambda, but I don't understand how to reference the consumerRecord variable, this is what I have already tried:

```
#{#consumerRecord.key().equals(T(com.example.kafkaconsumer.EventType).CREATE.toString())}
```

It fails with the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: 
Method call: Attempted to call method key() on null context object
```

This is what I'm trying to implement using SPEL:

```
@Bean
public RecordFilterStrategy<String, Foo> recordFilterStrategy() {
    return rec -> !Objects.equals(rec.key(), EventType.CREATE.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that JavaDocs one more time:

```
Set an {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy} bean
 * name
```

Since you already have a `recordFilterStrategy` bean, so that's enough for your to use in that `filter()` attribute:

```
 filter = "recordFilterStrategy"
```

No need to fight with a complex SpEL.

Comment: Also, the SpEL is not processed at runtime; it is evaluated once, during application context initialization; there is no such variable as `#consumerRecord`.

Comment: Just for my understanding - if I'm really stubborn and would like to fight with a SpEL - is this achievable at all? I understood `If a SpEL expression is provided (#{...}), the expression can either evaluate to a org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy instance` as an implication, that implementation itself can be provided or what is meant by instance here? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: See Gary's comment: called once at startup. So, this one is a valid SpEL `#{recordFilterStrategy}` - reference to a bean. Or this one: `#{T(com.my.proj.MyClass).staticMethodReturningRecordFilterStrategy()}`

Comment: Or `#{new MyRFS()}`.